# Convert str to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, string, numpy, opencv, byte

I'm creating a system to share video with opencv but I've got a problem.
I've a server and a client but when I send informations to the server, the must be bytes.
I send 2 things:

```
 ret, frame = cap.read()
```

ret is a booland frame is the data video, a numpy.ndarray
ret is not a problem but frame:
I convert it in string and then in bytes:

```
frame = str(frame).encode()
connexion_avec_serveur.send(frame)
```

I'd like now to convert again frame in a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: Why not use `frame.tobytes` and then `np.frombuffer` to recover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `str(frame).encode()` is wrong. If you print it to terminal, then you will find it is not the data of the frame.

An alternative method is to use `tobytes()` and `frombuffer()`.

```
## read
ret, frame = cap.read()
sz = frame.shape

## tobytes 
frame_bytes = frame.tobytes()
print(type(frame_bytes))
# <class 'bytes'>

## frombuffer and reshape 
frame_frombytes = np.frombuffer(frame_bytes, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(sz)
print(type(frame_frombytes))
## <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

## test whether they equal or not 
print(np.array_equal(frame, frame_frombytes))
```